# pipenv doesn't install django in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pipenv

[image: Error is occured during installing django in ubuntu.]

Cannot install django using pipenv**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended way to install Django.

```
Install pip. The easiest is to use the standalone pip installer. If your distribution already has pip installed, you might need to update it if it’s outdated. If it’s outdated, you’ll know because installation won’t work.

Take a look at venv. This tool provides isolated Python environments, which are more practical than installing packages systemwide. It also allows installing packages without administrator privileges. The contributing tutorial walks through how to create a virtual environment.

After you’ve created and activated a virtual environment, enter the command:

$ python -m pip install Django
```